# При запуске функции добавить название картинки в JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция удаления превью фотографии. Как можно сделать так, чтобы если удаляется картинка с путем `img/..`, то название картинки бы записывалось в `<input>` в формате `JSON`? Допустим, если я удалю обе картинки из кода ниже, чтобы в `JSON` оказалось такое значение `["img1.jpg"]`

```js
imagesList.on('click', '.delete-link', function () {
  var item = $(this).closest('.item'),
      id = item.data('id');
 
  delete queue[id];
 
  item.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="json_list" type="hidden" value="">

<ul id="uploadImagesList">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="img-wrapi">
      <img src="img/img1.jpg">
    </span>
    <span class="delete-link">Удалить</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="img-wrapi">
      <img src="img2.jpg">
    </span>
    <span class="delete-link">Удалить</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagesList.on('click', '.delete-link', function () {
  var item = $(this).closest('.item'),
      id = item.data('id');

  var src = item.find("img").attr("src");
  if (src && src.indexOf("/img") == 0) {
    var deleted = [];
    if ($(".json_list").val() != "") {
      deleted = JSON.parse($(".json_list").val());
    }
    deleted.push(src.replace("/img", ""));
    $(".json_list").val(JSON.stringify(deleted));
  }

  delete queue[id];
  item.remove();
});
```